# Why does my regex expression match every character?

Tags: java, regex

I want to exclude any characters except letters and numbers but when I run my program no matter what I enter I always enter the while loop.

```
System.out.println("Please enter the name of the next dancer");

while(!scan.hasNext("^[a-z0-9]+$/i"))
{

    System.out.println("Please ensure you only enter letters of the alphabet and numbers bewteen 0 and 9");
    scan.nextLine();

}
arrCelebs[celeb] = scan.next();
```

For example I enter "a" I get - System.out.println("Please enter the name of the next dancer");

And the same if I enter "%"

Comment: Just semantics, but as long as we are talking about decimal numbers, are there are any other numbers than those between 0 and 9? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/i` won't make it ignore case in Java, use:

```
"(?i)^[a-z0-9]+$"
```

Or simply:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
```

Another problem in your approach is that by default `^` matches start of text, not start of line, so if your first input will not match regex, then next one can't match it too since it will not be at start of text. So either make your anchors match start of line with multiline flag `(?m)` or simply remove `^`.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I still enter the while loop no matter what I enter.

Comment: How are you testing it? `!scan.hasNext("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")` return `false` if you enter `a`

Comment: @JerryMurphy Remove `^` anchor from your regex. If your first value will be incorrect then it certainly won't be at start of the entire text scanner read so far which means that `^` prevents you from matching any input. You can also add multiline flag to your regex to let this anchor represent start of *line*.

Comment: @Pshemo That fixed it. Can you write it as an answer? And explain where I was going wrong?

Comment: @JerryMurphy There is no need for second answer. I added explanation to this one (hope you don't mind @anubhava).

Comment: I ment you wrote it as a comment not as an answer

Comment: @Pshemo: Thanks so much for your comment and editing the answer. Sorry I stepped away for few minutes so couldn't edit it myself.